# The Media callback is executed after stopping on Phonegap/Android

Tags: html, cordova, media

I am using the HTML5 media object inside my cordova/android project. Those Media objects have a callback function that should be executed once the media finishes to play the Audio file, but it seems the callback is launched when the media are stopped and released too.
Why the success callback is being called when I stop/release the Media? How can I stop completely without launch the callback function?

Comment: I am using cordova 1.0.9 and Android 4.1 (API 16). Cordova & iOS does not have this problem.

Comment: You are probably on android, there is a bug. I'll looking into it.

Comment: I double checked you are seeing the correct behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean it should work on that way? Is it not an issue?

Comment: Yup, the success callback is invoked on a change of the state of the media to STOPPED no matter how it gets there.